# Word that means to overcomplicate or dress up a simple observation

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, synonyms

I am looking for a word that means overcomplicating a simple point. Essentially I need a verb for the word jargon. The sentence I am trying to fit in in is:

"These discussions, couched in the language of insurrection as if we were all insurgents leading the charge against elite power, **OBSCURE** the insipid observations that culture and our moral framework have changed."

Need to replace the word "obscure".

Comment: I'm not familiar with *tarted up*, but I've never heard *pimped out* used in this context. That phrase refers either to prostitution or to the upgrading of / addition of adornments to a physical object, most commonly a car or house.

Comment: Are you just saying that the language is too complicated, or are you also saying that it's too bellicose?

Comment: It seems to me that you are asking for a word that expresses what overcomplicated language does — not a word that means *overcomplicated language*.

Answer (score 1):

There is a verb for the word jargon:

> **jargonize** (*transitive verb*): to make into jargon

([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jargonize))

However, that does not necessarily fit well into your example sentence. Another alternative is:

> **obfuscate** (*transitive verb*): to make obscure

([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obfuscate))

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for a word that means overcomplicating a simple point.

How about **convolute**?

Definitions:

> *verb   make (an argument, story, etc.) complex and difficult to
> follow.* (Oxford Languages)

> *convolute - practice sophistry; change the meaning of or be vague
> about in order to mislead or deceive; "Don't twist my words"* ([www.thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com))

Quotes:

> *The convoluted tale of their former Belgravia apartment rivals that of
> the end to their marriage.* (Times, Sunday Times (2013))

> *Leave it to the Feds to convolute a simple concept.* (ocregister.com)

Answer (score 0):

The closest term I can think of is:

> **Sesquipedalian**, *adjective*: given to or characterized by the use of long words

Although, that word itself is excessive.

Maybe:

> **Verbose**, *adjective*: containing more words than necessary

Comment: The asker is looking for a verb.

Comment: Also you need to cite the sources of your definitions.